# Battery Voltage low when car is running. Should I be concerned?

Tags: battery, alternator, voltage, voltage-regulator

**Car: 2010 Mazda 3 GT 2.5L Manual 160,000KMs**

I purchased the car 3 months ago not knowing the history of the battery, I wanted to test it.

I measured the voltage across my battery using a voltmeter directly connected to the battery terminals. The following are the readings under different conditions:

1. Engine is not running = 12.6V
2. Engine is running (idle ~800RPM) = 13.6V
3. Engine RPM is kept at ~4000RPM = 13.6V

I do not have easy access to measure the voltage directly coming out of the alternator. From lot of articles I read from the internet, my voltage should be 14.0V when the engine is running.

**Is this normal or does this indicate some issue with either the alternator or the voltage regulator? Do I also need to load test the battery?**

Note: The car starts with no issues and there are no other indicators of a bad battery or charging system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't  worry too much.  You can go a little deeper in checking the system. But you will need a load tester. I wouldn't worry about 0.4v. You could turn on as many loads ad you can. 
Head lights/hi and low beam, a.c.,  blower  motor, and radio.  And check the voltage.

Comment: Normal should be considered a range, not just a set 14.0vdc output. I would suggest 13.5-14.2vdc is usually a better indicator of output. It really depends on the vehicle and how the charging system was designed.

Comment: upper voltage range can be 14.8v - does depend on the car though and the type of charging regime - mine can and has gone up to 15.2 but that is normal for my car. Your readings sound like the battery is fully charged.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal. No need to worry. Anything else we can look into?